# How can you tell if pizza dough has been kneaded enough?

Tags: dough, pizza

I am making pizza dough for the first time. I know that you can use the window test and the poke test for bread, to see if it has ben kneaded long enough. Can you use the same tests for pizza dough and bread sticks? Some of the recipes  say only knead for 2 minutes, other say 7-8 minutes. I can not find any tips for how to tell if it is kneaded enough.

Answer (score 3):

The window test works well for pizza as well and is really the only one of which I am aware. I do not believe the poke test will work as well.

Comment: That is what I thought,  I use the window test on all of my breads.  I usually do the poke test to. That way I'm double sure. I am new at bread making, I figure  I'm double covered.

Comment: The window pane test is for testing gluten formation and the poke test is generally for proofing, when to turn your dough while proofing. and testing weather you have proofed your loaf long enough and are ready to bake.